# Bunyan logger not printing "ERROR" log level in aws cloudwatch log

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, bunyan

We are using `Bunyan` lib for aws lambda function for cloud watch.
I am observing , when I print Bunyan logger with status `error` , it is printing error format as follows

```
{
    "name": "test-abc",
    "serviceID": ".......................",
    "requestID": "........................",
    "hostname": "................",
    "pid": 8,
    "function": "_testStore",
    "level": 50,
    "msg": "store_id is missing",
    "time": "2020-11-16T19:17:41.109Z",
    "v": 0
}
```

while, when I log the error using `console.error` function , I am getting error log in the below format

`2020-11-16 13:41:27.357 (-06:00) a.....  ERROR   store_id is missing`

As `ERROR` logLevel tag in cloud watch help , to generate cloud error matrix, how could I use Bunyan for the same to print `ERROR` tag before the JSON object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buyan format uses level as a decimal number where level `error` means `50`.

Please check the official documentation: https://github.com/trentm/node-bunyan#levels